# Python : from numpy.array to shapely.geometry

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, scatter, shapely

I am working on a project around scatter points and I need to find their concave hull.

I have seen an example on the web where the person creates scatter points with QGIS so that he has a .shp file that he can load with 'fiona' library. Then he works with the 'shapely' library.

During the algorithm, he has information about the points thanks to the .shp file, indeed each point would look like this when retrieved :

```
{'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (-1.8148148148148153, 1.207977207977208)}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '0', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'id', None)])}
```

then works with variables who are as follows :

```
<class 'shapely.geometry.point.Point'>
```

I would like to do the same with my own scatter points, but they are not included in an .shp files as they are numpy.array (just integer coordinates).

Do you know how I can still work with shapely objects without having .shp files ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can create `Point` objects directly in `shapely`. Check out the documentation [here](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#Point)

Comment: thanks that's actually really simple, I just didn't remember how to create objects haha...
:)